# Get timestring of user registered in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code to get the current logged in user's string to get echo the date registered

```
global $wp_query;
$registered = date_i18n( "M m, Y", strtotime( get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $wp_query->queried_object_id ) ) );
```

That gets the actual string. But I need a timestamp so I can run calculations with it.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got the answer! Did you grab this code from somewhere?

Take a look at the code you've got:

```
$registered = date_i18n( "M m, Y", strtotime( get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $wp_query->queried_object_id ) ) );
```

The very first thing you're doing is using WordPress' [`get_the_author_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) to return the `user_registered` value from the database (a `datetime`, `0000-00-00 00:00:00` value)

Then you're using PHP's [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) which converts that value **into a Unix Timestamp** which is what you want, I presume.

Then, once you've got that timestamp, you're using WordPress' [`date_i18n()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/) function to convert that timestamp *back* into a human readable time, based on locale (or the date format if no locale is set†)

> † Do you mean to have it set to `'M m, Y'`? That's "[3-letter name of month], [number of month with leading 0], [4 digit year]. `j` or `d` returns the number of the day. Take a look at [formatting Date & Time](https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/) for more info.

Basically, you can remove that last step to get your timestamp that you can then use like any other integer:

```
$registered = strtotime( get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $wp_query->queried_object_id ) );
```

Comment: Do you still have `global $wp_query`?

Comment: Yup. global $wp_query is still at the top of the code. Sill returned blank